# How can we more optimze below switch code?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Below code is working fine. But I want optimze it . How can i achive the same functionality in less line. Is there any chances to improve the below code. Little help will be highly appreciated.

```
  setDefaultIndex(selectedFit, defaults, array, fab) {
    const defaultValue =  defaults.filter(item => item.fitCode === selectedFit);
    let selectedIndex: number;
    switch (fab) {
      case 'exterior':
        selectedIndex = array.findIndex(fabric => fabric.id === defaultValue[0].exteriorFabricCode);
        break;
     case 'body':
       selectedIndex = array.findIndex(fabric => fabric.id === defaultValue[0].bodyLiningCode);
       break;
     case 'sleeve':
       selectedIndex = array.findIndex(fabric => fabric.id === defaultValue[0].sleeveLiningCode);
       break;
     default:
       selectedIndex = 0;
       break;
    }
    return selectedIndex;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an object (or a Map) that maps `fab` value to key in defaults (`fabToKey`).
2. Create a function (`getPredicate`) that accepts a value and returns a predicate.
3. In `setDefaultIndex` get the value of `fab` from `fabToKey`. If key is falsy return 0;
4. Get the `defaultValue` by using `Array.find()`. Note: you need to handle the not found case - ie find returns `null`.
5. Run `findIndex()` with the predicate created by invoking `getPredicate` with the `defaultValue[key]`.

Example (not tested):

```
const fabToKey = { exterior: 'exteriorFabricCode', body: 'bodyLiningCode', sleeve: 'sleeveLiningCode' };

const getPredicate = value => ({ id }) => id === value;

setDefaultIndex(selectedFit, defaults, array, fab) {
  const key = fabToKey[fab];

  if (!key) return 0;

  const defaultValue = defaults.find(item => item.fitCode === selectedFit);

  // do something if defaultValue is null - ie selectedFit wasn't found

  return array.findIndex(getPredicate(defaultValue[key]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is enough?:

```
setDefaultIndex(selectedFit, defaults, array, fab) {
  const defaultValue =  defaults.filter(item => item.fitCode === selectedFit);
  let selectedIndex: number = 0;
  const id = fab => {
    case 'exterior': return defaultValue[0].exteriorFabricCode
    case 'body': return defaultValue[0].bodyLiningCode'
    case 'sleeve': return defaultValue[0].sleeveLiningCode'
    default: false
  }
  return id(fab) ? array.findIndex(f => f.id === id(fab)) : selectedIndex
}
```